# What is an efficent and effective way to find a reputable private guide for a backpacking trip?

Tags: backpacking, mountains, california, rocky-mountains

My [first question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8873/where-can-we-go-backpacking-out-west-under-8-500-feet-that-has-much-of-the-feel) on TGO was about low altitude trips that have the feel of much higher elevations. I asked that question because of the declining physical capacity of my husband.  I received spectacular answers, which we were not able to take advantage of because my husband's health declined further soon after.  Hiking is now out of the question for him, as is camping or even a long plane trip.  So I am now asking a related, but definitely different question.

I can still hike, although I do not know if I can still easily acclimatize. **But** **I do not want to carry a pack** other than a day-pack **and** I don't think it wise to go off on my own on a multi-day trip, **and** I don't like groups. I'm at a loss with what to do.

Ideally, I'd like a private guide(s) who will do the carrying and the cooking and provide most of the gear.  I don't want to schlep more than personal stuff and possibly my own sleeping bag on an airplane.  That is, I am looking for a full-service private guide who works in the California Sierra or a comparable place.

At this point, someone is saying this is a shopping//price Question!  **It is absolutely not a price question.**  I have a pretty good idea about the cost.  Nor am I asking for a list of reputable private guides (although I sure would not refuse to look at such a list!)

**I am asking (a) if such a service exists in the Sierra (or in Sierra-like terrain) and (b) if it does, what is an efficient and effective way to find reputable candidates.**

I said Sierra-like terrain because I was greatly intrigued by the [answer of @gerrit](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8873/where-can-we-go-backpacking-out-west-under-8-500-feet-that-has-much-of-the-feel/8888#8888) to my first question, although it looks wet.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find one outside of reading reviews, but there surely are a number of horse packers in certain areas. Could your husband not ride a horse either? I'm thinking you could ride up to a base camp and you could do some days hikes while he fishes perhaps. Packers could come pick you up after a few days. I know such outfits exist near the Wind River Range.

Comment: @topshot Thank you for the suggestion, but my husband is not capable of camping or even taking a long plane trip.  The packer is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I was hoping for the best of both worlds for both of you. I think a packer is more of what you are after vs a guide unless you want them to stay with you full-time. On that note, I would not say it is unwise for you to go on your own for several days if you're in decent health and condition. I know of several women 70s/80s that pack solo. You will go slower than you once did, but that gives you more time to enjoy the scenery. ;)

Comment: Related to what @topshot said you could look for a hunting/nature photography guide. They're probably more accustomed to organizing a trip like you're describing than an outfitter. You also might try using your social network(s). We don't really know each other beyond our interactions here but I'd be willing to go with you on a trip for free if my personal circumstances would have allowed it. I'm sure there's other people you know, even tangentially, that feel the same way.

Comment: @Erik Good suggestion, and what a generous spirit you have.