# I need a personal guide/assistant for backpacking

Tags: backpacking, united-states, wilderness, california, colorado

I have probably asked this question before, but I have not received a specific enough answer.

My husband and I backpacked for more than four decades, but he died in early 2019 --  and then Covid. I am getting old -- OK, I **am** old. But I am not ready to take up knitting, Bingo, television and dandling babies on my knee.  I'd rather be dead.

What I need, as opposed to merely want, is a personal assistant who will carry everything except a day-hiker's worth of stuff, give me an occasional literal hand on tricky patches, be patient, set up camp, cook and also suggest routes (in addition to the ones that I know) that are mostly above timberline, but not too high.  Areas I know very well:  Sierra Nevada and parts of the Rocky Mountains.  I will certainly consider other places, but not brown bear habitat. Duration of trip:  10 days or so.

I may need two people, because I don't think one person can carry essentially everything for two people.  Or have I forgotten the capabilities of the young and strong?

As I said, I am highly experienced, but no longer limber or fast or blessed with unending stamina.  I have excellent judgment of my capabilities in any given situation.

**I am willing to pay handsomely.** Where do I find the service -- nay, the paragon(s) -- I am looking for?  A particular packer, organization, or what, where?  Group trips are out of the question; I don't like crowds, especially in TGO.

I am a woman, and have a small preference for a woman, but this is not crucial.  Obviously, references are important.

THANKS!

Comment: Guide services and horse (or llama) packing outfits, etc. would be places to start. I've seen group trips (or even just 'family') advertised. but I'm sure for enough $$$ they would provide more personalized services.

Comment: Googling 'llama trips new mexico' gets things like "What's llama trekking? Llama trekking is hiking and camping in New Mexico's pristine wilderness, with a woolly hiking buddy and knowledgeable wilderness guide."

Comment: Length and group size will be the sticking points. Have you tried to contact some guiding companies to see what they can do? [The Colorado Trail Foundation](https://coloradotrail.org/trail/guided-trekking/) seems like it might be a good place to start. If they can't do it, they may be able to suggest someone who can?

Comment: Or [these guys](https://coloradowildernessridesandguides.com/guided-adventures/hiking-peak-ascents/), who seem to do custom trips. [Here's an altitude one](https://coloradowildernessridesandguides.com/product/epic-summit-series/): $3670 for 1 person: I have no affiliation with either linked company

Comment: This seems identical to your [previous question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22243/what-is-an-efficent-and-effective-way-to-find-a-reputable-private-guide-for-a-ba). If you are just looking for additional answers/exposure a bounty seems more appropriate than a 2nd question

Comment: If there are establishments catering to the outdoors market (gear and supplies shops, inns, cabins, outdoor clubs, mountain clubs, University clubs, etc.) I would put up a notice in their bulletin boards. And thoroughly vet any applicant.

Comment: @ab2 - I'll close as dupe. That will ping some more attention at your older version, but it is still a bit of a shopping recommendations question, so may get closed overall.

Comment: @bob1  Thanks ....